# error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found when running ios build

Tags: flutter, flutter-ios

I've seen this question asked a lot, but none of the solutions I've found have worked for me. As of this week I started getting errors like:

```
url_launcher-5.7.10/ios/Classes/FLTURLLauncherPlugin.h:5:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
```

It's not always from the url_launcher package. It seems to just cycle through which package it's going to throw that error from. I've tried the following things:

- Removing the ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec file and running flutter clean
- Toggled between master, stable and beta Flutter builds in combination with removing the Flutter.podspec.
- Removing the whole ios directory and running flutter create . to re-create.
- Re-generating Podfile.
- Trying different versions of the packages that wind up throwing the error.
- Various combinations of the above listed items.

Nothing seems to work, so I'm at a bit of a loss here. The android app is still building fine.

Dependencies section of my pubspec:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.2.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  admob_flutter: ^1.0.1
  after_layout: ^1.0.7+2
  ant_icons: ^1.0.0
  app_review: ^2.0.1
  apple_sign_in: ^0.1.0
  auto_size_text: ^2.1.0
  barcode_scan: ^2.0.2
  basic_utils: ^2.6.3
  bubble_tab_indicator: ^0.1.4
  built_value: ^7.1.0
  built_collection: ^4.3.2
  chips_choice: ^2.0.1
  cloud_firestore: ^0.14.1+2
  dio: 3.0.10
  equatable: ^1.2.5
  file_picker: ^2.1.5
  firebase_core: ^0.5.2+1
  firebase_auth: ^0.18.3+1
  firebase_analytics: ^6.2.0
  firebase_in_app_messaging: ^0.2.2
  flutter_bloc: ^6.1.1
  flutter_chips_input: ^1.9.5
  firebase_crashlytics: ^0.2.3+1
  firebase_dynamic_links: ^0.6.2
  firebase_messaging: 7.0.3
  flutter_form_builder: 4.2.0
  firebase_remote_config: 0.3.0+3
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.8.1
  flutter_keyboard_visibility: ^4.0.2
  flutter_signin_button: ^1.1.0
  flutter_spinkit: ^4.1.2+1
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.3.3
  flutter_svg: ^0.19.2+1
  flutter_switch: 0.2.0
  flutter_typeahead: "<=1.9.1"
  flutter_webview_plugin: ^0.3.11
  font_awesome_flutter: 8.11.0
  get_it: ^5.0.6
  google_sign_in: ^4.5.9
  http: ^0.12.2
  in_app_purchase: ^0.3.5+1
  loading_overlay: ^0.2.1
  loadmore: ^1.0.4
  page_slider: ^0.0.2
  path: ^1.7.0
  path_provider: ^1.6.27
  percent_indicator: ^2.1.9
  share: 0.6.3+6
  sticky_headers: ^0.1.8+1
  tab_indicator_styler: ^1.0.0
  transparent_image: ^1.0.0
  url_launcher: ^5.7.10

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.1+1

dependency_overrides:
  analyzer: ^0.41.2
  intl: ^0.16.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_driver:
    sdk: flutter
  test: any
  build_runner: 1.11.0
  built_value_generator: ^7.1.0
```

Comment: $ rm ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec and then
$ flutter clean

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/70895#issuecomment-744734693

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried that multiple times already and it doesn't solve it.

Answer (score 8):

I recently had this issue, executing these commands in Terminal helped me to resolve the issue.

```
$ rm ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec
$ rm -fr ios/Pods
$ rm ios/Podfile
$ flutter clean
```

Comment: I have tried so many solutions, but only this worked for me.Thanks!

Comment: That worked perfect for me. Thanks

Comment: not working for me on Mac m1

Comment: if you are on Mac M1, after 3rd step, run this, ```arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update```

Comment: @imgkl Doesn’t work for me

Comment: rm Podfile.lock or Podfile?

Comment: no working for me

Comment: ````$ rm ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec
$ rm -fr ios/Pods
$ rm ios/Podfile.lock
$ arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update````

try these maybe.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the share extension and none of the answers on SO worked for me. What did work was adjusting[image] my Runner build phases so that they are in the order, as seen in the image.